# When to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter and when to use Enter in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I don't understand when I should use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and when to just use <kbd>Enter</kbd> in Excel.

Can someone help me understand the difference between them and how they should be used?

Comment: What do you think the difference between the two is?

Comment: Hmmm... @DerHochstapler Thanks for that helpful comment!

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers You're welcome

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**For single cell formulas**

There's no completely consistent rule.

In general when you use ranges in formulas or functions that normally only apply to single cells then you need <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.....so if you use

`=IF(A1=3,1,0)`

that's a straightforward formula which can be normally entered......but if you change it to

`=SUM(IF(A1:A10=3,1,0))`

.....then you now need <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

....but some functions can process ranges or arrays without CSE, e.g. `SUMPRODUCT` and `LOOKUP`......and some functions **always** need CSE, e.g. `TRANSPOSE`

...and to confuse you further, typically if you use an "array constant" in place of an array, e.g.

`=SUM(IF({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}=3,1,0))`

...that doesn't need CSE.......and there are ways to make CSE formulas into non-CSE, e.g., this needs CSE

`=INDEX(B2:B10,MATCH(1,(A2:A10="x")*(C2:C10="y"),0))`

but this avoids CSE to do the same thing with an extra INDEX function

`=INDEX(B2:B10,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2:A10="x")*(C2:C10="y"),0),0))`

**for multi-cell formulas**

these are formulas that return an "array" of values, e.g. this formula returns as "array" of 21 values

`=FREQUENCY(A1:A100,B1:B20)`

so you can select a range of 21 cells to display all those values - such formulas need to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> after the entry range has been selected

Comment: Also, (Ctrl)+(Enter) lets you enter the same simple (single-cell) formula in multiple cells (all the selected cells) simultaneously.

Comment: Simple... Right!

Comment: CSE = acronym meaning CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

Comment: You say that with `=SUM(IF(A1:A10=3,1,0))` you "need" to use CSE, but it works well with just Enter: that produces 6 if I have A2=3, A8=3 and other cells are not 3. Did it change with latest Excel versions? (I use Excel 365)