# Create a Table that Filters Data and Sorts Unique Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365, autodesk-inventor

I am trying to generate a list of unique values in excel based on a unique list of items.

Basically, I need to create a list that Sorts and Assigns a Part Name Based on Width and Length. Then counts the total of that part. I can get this to work fine if the list does not contain multiple unique lengths. For example

**I've read through this:** [Excel '10 Formula to find & sum a row based on the intersection of 2 data points. (ie. Name(row), Month(column)](https://superuser.com/questions/883601/excel-10-formula-to-find-sum-a-row-based-on-the-intersection-of-2-data-points) & I think the key difference is I need to get the name & total by the name without making it unique

Also, this is easy in a pivot table, but I'd like to do it based on formulas.

```
Part-G = 37
Part-G = 37
```

sorts fine, totals to Part-G | Quantity 2 | @ 37"

```
Part-G = 38"
Part-G = 20"
```

totals to Part-G | Quantity 2 | @ first discovered length but should total to Part-G | Quantity 1 | 38" and Part-G | Quantity 1 | 20"

***Extra Info:**
This is generated in Woodwork for Inventor and exported to a Bill of Material Template - this is isn't required to solve the problem, but there might be a way to sort in Inventor that I'm unfamiliar with, so I'll include that here.*

For example

**Input:**

| PART | WIDTH | LENGTH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D-R | 1.75 | 37 |
| D-R | 1.75 | 37 |
| D-R | 1.75 | 32 |
| A-M | 1.75 | 31 |
| G-R | 3 | 20 |

**Output I need:**

| MATCH WIDTH |
| --- |
| 1.75 |

| PART_2 | Quantity | LENGTH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D-R | 2 | 37 |
| D-R | 1 | 32 |
| A-M | 1 | 31 |

I include the 'width

Here is the formulas for each, I simplified cell references with names for the sake of this example:

| PART |
| --- |
| UNIQUE(FILTER(PART,WIDTH = MatchWidth),"") |
| filter spills into these cells |

| Quantity |
| --- |
| (IF(SUM(IF(FILTER(*PART*,*WIDTH*=*MatchWidth*)=*Part_2*,1,0))>0,SUM(IF(FILTER(*PART*,*WIDTH*=*MatchWidth*)=*PART_1*,1,0)),"") |

| Quantity |
| --- |
| INDEX(*LENGTH*,MATCH(*PART_2*,*PART*,0)) |

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem statement: You want to count the number of unique parts (part + length) for a given match width.

The key here is you search by the unique id (that is a concatenation of the part number and the length). So all unique id's matching you match width:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(PART & ";" & LENGTH, WIDTH = MATCHWIDTH))
```

Use the above formula as a help column (lets call it IDs). Then PART2 is:

```
=LEFT(IDs, FIND(";", IDs)-1)
```

And LENGTH2 is:

```
=RIGHT(IDs, LEN(IDs)-FIND(";", IDs))
```

And quantity is a simple SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(PART, PART2, LENGTH, LENGTH2)
```